# Passing structure's named fields to other functions

Tags: go

This is my first `golang` program rather than just reading docs so please bear with me.

I've a structure like:- (comes from a parsed yaml)

```
type GLBConfig struct {
    GLBList []struct {
        Failover string `json:"failover" yaml:"failover"`
        GLB      string `json:"glb" yaml:"glb"`
        Pool     []struct {
            Fqdn              string `json:"fqdn" yaml:"fqdn"`
            PercentConsidered int    `json:"percent_considered" yaml:"percent_considered"`
        } `json:"pool" yaml:"pool"`
    } `json:"glb_list" yaml:"glb_list"`
}
```

Now, in my main function, there's a for loop which does processing of each GLB:-

```
for _, glb := range config_file.GLBList {
    processGLB(glb)
}
```

**What will be the function definition of `processGLB` to receive this type?**

I tried doing this but it doesn't work and **I would like to know why.**

```
func processGLB(glb struct{}) {
    fmt.Println(glb)
}

./glb_workers.go:42: cannot use glb (type struct { Failover string "json:\"failover\" yaml:\"failover\""; Glb string "json:\"glb\" yaml:\"glb\""; Pool []struct { Fqdn string "json:\"fqdn\" yaml:\"fqdn\""; PercentConsidered int "json:\"percent_considered\" yaml:\"percent_considered\"" } "json:\"pool\" yaml:\"pool\"" }) as type struct {} in argument to processGLB
```

Then, some googling later, this works.

```
func processGLB(glb interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(glb)
}
```

Is it a good idea to do this? **Why do I have to use interfaces to pass a simple structure named field?**

In the end, what's the most elegant/right way to do this in golang?

**EDIT:**

Simple solution was to define the structure separately.

```
type GLBList struct {
        Failover string `json:"failover" yaml:"failover"`
        GLB      string `json:"glb" yaml:"glb"`
        Pool     []struct {
                Fqdn              string `json:"fqdn" yaml:"fqdn"`
                PercentConsidered int    `json:"percent_considered" yaml:"percent_considered"`
        } `json:"pool" yaml:"pool"`
}

type GLBConfig struct {
        GLBs []GLBList `json:"glb_list" yaml:"glb_list"`
}
```

And then a function definition like:-

```
func processGLB(glb GLBList) {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really consider define the struct explicitly and reuse it. The all point of using a langauge with support for static typing is to define your types whenever you can, it helps the compiler to find bugs and produce a faster code.

Also, if you would like to have a more compact code you can use the concept of [anonymous fields](http://golangtutorials.blogspot.co.il/2011/06/anonymous-fields-in-structs-like-object.html), although I don't think that is the best scenario for this.

Comment: So, to consume each `structure`, I define a separate structure? That seems like a lot of duplicate code to me.

Comment: You define one structure and then an Array. Like you did in your code:
struct A{}
struct B{
 []x A
}

Comment: I've have updated the answer to have the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

GLBList is defined as Array of struct. In go, there is nothing called as struct{}. All the go type implements empty interface, hence to pass struct (in this case struct without name) empty interface can be used. For more details http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go